# Using another column in where clause other than primary key

Tags: mysql, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am converting existing Query to StrongLoop Loopback ORM and have hit a standstill.

My Query :

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT(tog.grp_id) AS grp_id,
  tog.grp_desc AS grp_desc
FROM trmpt_usr_grps tug
LEFT JOIN trmpt_org_grps tog ON tog.grp_id = tug.grp_id
LEFT JOIN trmpt_users tu ON tu.usr_id = tug.usr_id
WHERE tu.usr_username LIKE ? ;
```

Now I have successfully made the ORM relations for the same but I want to use `usr_username` column which is **not** a foreign key in where clause like this `{"where":{"usr_username":"rohit"}}`

currently this works `{"where":{"usr_id":2}}` and usr_id and usr_username are columns on same table

Comment: use scope filter inside relation...more details look this link https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Include+filter

Comment: i am starting again and have removed all relations... ill try and place everything again and let you know.